# Cannot view variables values from Java sources during debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

While debugging a Java program, I cannot view variables values in java source code, for example in function Integer.valueOf(). I try to add variables in Expressions or Inspect, but get 'a cannot be resolved'

Comment: Sources are attached and I can debug source code step by step

Comment: it's not possible to diagnose your problem without more information. Make sure that you have clean'ed and refresh'ed your project sdo you don't have anything out of date

Comment: have cleaned and refreshed the project. same problem occurs

Comment: can you see the variables or arguments for you own classes? Since you mentioned java.lang.Integer, I feel I need to point out that JRE classes are (usually) compiled without debugging information, so argument and variable names for these classes are not available during debugging sessions.

Comment: I cannot see both arguments and variables. And how can I correct it? The problem too is that I see *.class file in editor, not *.java, although I have attached src.zip

Answer (score 0):

This is known problem. Typically you can see the argument values as arg0, arg1 etc and sometimes member variables. If lhballoti is right and the problem is that the JDK is compiled without debug information try to compile it yourself from sources (src.zip). I believe that it is hard to compile whole JDK but I think that you can compile only interesting classes. Then push this classes into bootclasspath when you are running your java program (using `-Xbootclasspath/p`).

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

'a' is not a local variable in this method, however I don't think the JRE classes are enabled with full debugging information.  It might not be possible to see local variables in the JRE.